# Deadlock in channels communication between two packages - Golang

Tags: go, package, deadlock, channel

Deadlock in channels communication between two packages - Golang.

I have two packages that are communicated by two channels. One is main and the other has a function. When I run it, I obtain a deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    functionspackage "GoEjemplos/subFolder"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ChannelSendData := make(chan functionspackage.FunctionStruct, 1)
    defer close(ChannelSendData)

    data := functionspackage.FunctionStruct{
        FieldOne: 3.56,
        FieldTwo: 23,
    }

    ChannelSendData <- data

    wg.Add(1)
    go functionspackage.FunctionExt(ChannelSendData, &wg)

    recibe := <-functionspackage.ChannelOutFunct

    fmt.Println("channelOut: ", recibe)

    close(functionspackage.ChannelOutFunct)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

The other package is

```
package functionspackage

import "sync"

type FunctionStruct struct {
    FieldOne float64
    FieldTwo int
}

var ChannelOutFunct chan float64

func FunctionExt(RecibeChan chan FunctionStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) (ChannelOutFunct chan float64) {

    reciveData := <-RecibeChan

    result := reciveData.FieldOne * float64(reciveData.FieldTwo)

    ChannelOutFunct <- result

    wg.Done()

    return ChannelOutFunct
}
```

This is the deadlock.

```
PS C:\Go-Project\src\GoEjemplos> go run main.go
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive (nil chan)]:
main.main()
        C:/Go-Project/src/GoEjemplos/main.go:32 +0x13d

goroutine 19 [chan send (nil chan)]:
GoEjemplos/subFolder.FunctionExt(0xc0000d4000, 0xc0000a2070, 0xc0000c9f18)
        C:/Go-Project/src/GoEjemplos/subFolder/functionsPackage.go:19 +0x85
created by main.main
        C:/Go-Project/src/GoEjemplos/main.go:30 +0x11a
exit status 2
PS C:\Go-Project\src\GoEjemplos>
```

Could you explain it to me where is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The channel `functionspackage.ChannelOutFunct` is not initialized, thus it is a nil channel. Writing to a nil-channel or reading from a nil-channel will always block.

https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms

Comment: I appreciate your response. Anyway, I need if you can help me a little more. I understand that the channel is not initialized and that causes the error. But I don't know where I should initialize it because to my understanding it was already initialized in the functionspackage package (var ChannelOutFunct chan float64)
If I remove that channel and initialize it to main, how would it relate to the return of the function found in the other package?
My apologies for the inconvenience. I'm trying to learn Go programming.

Comment: It is not initialized, it is declared, so it is nil. You can declare and initialize it: `var ChannelOutFunct = make(chan float64)`. You can also initialize it in `main`. It being in a different package doesn't have any significance here.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. This is the code

```
package main

import (
    packagefunctions "GoEjemplos/subFolder"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var ChannelSendData = make(chan packagefunctions.FunctionStruct, 0)
    defer close(ChannelSendData)
    var ChanReturn = make(chan float64)
    defer close(ChanReturn)

    data := packagefunctions.FunctionStruct{
        FieldOne: 3.56,
        FieldTwo: 2,
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() { ChannelSendData <- data }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        ChanReturn = packagefunctions.FunctionExt(ChannelSendData, &wg)
        recibeChanReturn := <-ChanReturn
        fmt.Println("channelOut: ", recibeChanReturn)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

the other package is

```
package packagefunctions

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type FunctionStruct struct {
    FieldOne float64
    FieldTwo int
}

func FunctionExt(ChanIn chan FunctionStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) chan float64 {
    reciveData, ok := <-ChanIn
    if ok == false {
        fmt.Println("channel closed")
    }
    var result float64
    result = reciveData.FieldOne * float64(reciveData.FieldTwo)
    var ChannelReturn = make(chan float64, 1)
    defer close(ChannelReturn)
    ChannelReturn <- result
    wg.Done()
    return ChannelReturn
}
```